# .Net Regex from Powershell not working as expected

Tags: .net, powershell

.Net Regex not working as expected.  The following should produce success $true. Any Ideas?

```
PS C:\Users\john\Desktop\ser> $s = "N:3"

PS C:\Users\john\Desktop\ser> using namespace System.Text.RegularExpressions

PS C:\Users\john\Desktop\ser> $s
N:3
PS C:\Users\john\Desktop\ser> $m = [Regex]::Match("N:", $s)

PS C:\Users\john\Desktop\ser> $m

Groups   : {0}
Success  : False
Name     : 0
Captures : {}
Index    : 0
Length   : 0
Value    :
```

Success = $false?  What's going on here?

However the following C# Code reports Sucesss:

```
string s = "N:";
var m = Regex.Match("N:", s);
if (m.Success) {
    MessageBox.Show("Success!");
}
else {
    MessageBox.Show("No Match");
}
```

When I run this C# code snipplet, it reports Success.

Answer (score 0):

False alarm. I just realized that I have the arguments switched.

```
PS C:\Users\john\Desktop\ser> $s = "N:3"

PS C:\Users\john\Desktop\ser> using namespace System.Text.RegularExpressions

PS C:\Users\john\Desktop\ser> $s
N:3

# Switch Arguments around
PS C:\Users\john\Desktop\ser> $m = [Regex]::Match($s, "N:")

PS C:\Users\john\Desktop\ser> $m

Groups   : {0}
Success  : True
Name     : 0
Captures : {0}
Index    : 0
Length   : 2
Value    : N:
```